# Forcing user to new page in php. (PHP newbie)

Tags: php

Hello  I'm a newbie web programmer.
My background is writing Windows applications with sql.

I'm putting together my 1st data entry screens in Php.

I have a search form that links to a form that displays records in a grid.
On each row of the grid I have a delete url to allow the user to remove a record.
This links to a form delete.php (which calls the sql to remove the record).

Ideally I would like to automatically take the user back to the search form rather than forcing the user to click on a link to do so.

I have used ob_start with the header to do this elsewhere but cannot get it to work on this page.
Is there another way to do it?

(Using php 5 as part of LAMP)
file delete.php

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['recordID'];
//ob_start();
require_once('connections/local.php'); 

mysql_select_db($database_local, $local);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM user_access WHERE id = {$id}") or die(mysql_error());
echo("Record ".$id." deleted");
echo("<br>");
//header("location:http://localhost/search7.htm);
//ob_flush();
echo("<a href=\"http://localhost/search7.htm\">Search for Members</a>");

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for swift reply and interesting answers.

I went for the simplest approach, did without any screen output to the delete.php and it worked fine.

I now realise that the [php] tag + newbie bring back lots of useful questions.

Comment: to "sanitize" your query, you have to either `$id = intval($_GET['recordID']);` or use `mysql_real_escape_string()` as recommended, **but** obligatory put your variable in quotes in the query, `...WHERE id = '$id'"...` Otherwise, without quotes, mysql_real_escape_string would help nothing. Any piece of data you put into query should be treated like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a `Location` header, there's no reason to `echo` *anything* to the browser, so you might as well `exit()` immediately:

```
<?php 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['recordID']);
require_once('connections/local.php'); 
mysql_select_db($database_local, $local);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM user_access WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: http://localhost/search7.htm");
exit();
?>
```

**IMPORTANT: You are also vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)** (fixed above via [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string))

Comment: OMG newbies strikes again. You have fixed nothing.

Comment: Did you mean to comment on a different answer? This answer fixes two issues.

Comment: No, I meant to comment this very ignorant answer. No injection has been fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used `mysql_real_escape_string`... I used PHP before the function even existed, and have since moved on to mature languages.

Comment: That's not an excuse. Any slashing function does the same. If you don't know PHP, why bother to answer that language questions at all?

Comment: @Dolph, LOL, it was only one character. No problemo ;)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you've got a SQL injection problem. **Always** sanitize your form input:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['recordID']);
```

Second, you can use the `header()` method to redirect the user:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/search7.htm');
```

but you can only do this if you haven't sent any output to the user. For this reason you'll often see people using output buffers to give them the option of doing an HTTP redirect. For this reason I find a function like this helpful:

```
function redirect($url) {
  while (ob_end_clean()) {
    // do nothing
  }
  header("Location: $url");
}
```

So you can then do this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "...some html...";
header('Location: /new/url.html'); // this will fail
redirect('/new/url.html'); // this will succeed
...
```

If you want to display a page temporarily try outputting something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15; url=http://localhost/search7.htm">
  <title>Delete Record</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>You have deleted a record.</p>
  <a href="http://localhost/search7.htm"><<< Back</a>
</body>
```

This will automatically redirect the user back after 15 seconds if they don't click the back link before then.

Comment: Agree with most, but can't resist to comment on an error: Actually, by virtue of the output buffering (ob_start()), you CAN use a `header('Location: ...');` as you describe, and it does succeed. It will use a 301 or 302 code normally, and only 1xx, 204 and 304 do not include a message body (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3), the rest may include it, although for 301's & 302's its obviously seldom seen. No need to 'clean up' the output.

Comment: @Col. Insulting people doesn't win you any arguments.

Comment: @Col. [sanitize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanitize): "to make more acceptable by removing unpleasant or undesired features". Ergo mysql_real_escape_string sanitizes input.

Comment: @Yacoby I don't play and I don't need to win anything. I have just pointed to ignorant answer, while the answerer can educate himself with one of numerous links in this topic. And mysql_real_escape_string does not remove any characters. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong with this line before you commented it?

```
//header("location:http://localhost/search7.htm);
```

That forces the browser off to another page. Two other options though (both go in `<head>`):

- Javascript:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">document.location.href = "http://url";</script>
  ```
- Meta refresh:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://url" />
  ```

Comment: I think you can't echo anything before header().

Comment: There's also output buffer code in there (counters that problem). The OP has been through this already.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have there should work, just like cletus suggested, but you need to put`//header("location:http://localhost/search7.htm);` before you echo/print **anything** (html code, php code, etc.) in your page, because it will mean that the headers were already sent. Its better explained 
[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into an AJAX solution.  That way you can delete the record without having to ever navigate away from the search page.  A good javascript library will make the operation pretty simple, and it would a fun and interesting project for someone new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible improvements not mentioned in the previous answers:

1. I would suggest using `POST` to process your database modifications instead of `GET`. That way you will avoid accidental deletions if someone has some kind of a web-accelerator installed (a program that pre-fetches web-pages by following / loading all links in a page).
2. About the sql injection vulnerability problem; if you are talking about a numeric ID, I would use `(int) $_GET['recordID']` or `intval($_GET['recordID'])` to make sure that the ID is an integer. No `mysql_real_escape_string()` needed.